# Distinct count no fastreport

Tags: delphi, fast-reports

Como fazer um `Distinct Count` no *FastReport*?

Tenho o relatório:

Nome  -  sexo
 
João  -  m
João  -  m
Maria -  f

No `Count` normal, o resultado seria 3, porém quero um que pegue apenas a quantidade de linhas que não repitam o campo nome. No caso o resultado seria 2.

Alguém consegue me ajudar? Isso é só um exemplo. Não tenho como fazer um `group by` no *db* porque tenho vários campos.

Answer (score 0):

Tanto quanto sei não tens nada feito para isso no FastReports. A função count nao tem parametros para te dar apenas o distinct.

O melhor é mesmo fazeres na query, se não queres fazer o group by podes sempre fazer algo como

```
Select a.nome,a.sexo,(Select count(*) from pessoas b where b.nome=a.nome) 'CountDistinct' from pessoas a Where condicao
```

Pode ser um pouco overkill, mas para querys simples, diria que resultava